# EU Blue Card to Germany or Working Visa permit

Tags: germany, working-visas, resident-permit, blue-card

I'm a bit confused about one of the particular Blue Card  requirements - "the job must be relevant to the qualifications, i.e. the skills acquired through the university degree must be at least partly or indirectly required for the job" .

I have a law degree, but I'm an security/privacy consultant in my life and that is the job I've got in Germany.

Now  I can explain that for my role/position in Germany company as Security/Privacy consultant, the privacy knowledge of regulations  comes from my Law degree and the internship in the law firm  from the past in which i worked as an intern in Tech Regulation and Privacy Department and afterwards as Privacy Data Consultant.

Is that explanation sufficient to prove that the skills acquired through the university are at least partly or indirectly required for the job?

If the above stated is not sufficient in my case to be regarded for  "the qualifications"  maybe I can or I should be referring only to "the qualifications" as the international certifications in that I have in Cyber Security like CCSP?

Comment: Do you in fact find yourself using the knowledge you gained and the skills you developed in your law education?  If so then you should have a fairly easy time establishing that your job is relevant to your qualifications.  Even if you don't use them, I suspect that "at least partly or indirectly" is a pretty low bar to clear.

Comment: how do I exactly prove that? My contract just says that I'm going to work in the field of security, the job name what I applied for is not mentioned directly in the contract. The only way I think I can prove  "at least partly or indirectly" it's to provide the job description that I applied for the interview - as it says  that part of the job is to communicate with the central legal, compliance and data governance teams.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have experience with the practical side of this, so I can't answer "how do I exactly prove that?"  Otherwise I would have posted an answer rather than a comment.  Perhaps someone with some practical experience of the application process will be able to answer.